# Add method to existing python module (boost python)?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I've embedded a Python interpreter in my C++ application, and also exported some classes that can be called in the interpreter.

Now this application also loads plug-ins (DLL file), and I want to be able to add new methods when the plugin is loaded, but I can't find how to do that after a day of Googling. :/

MainApp calls

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("mymodule", &PyInit_mymodule);
Py_Initialize();
bp::import("mymodule");
```

and bp::import calls init, ie:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ROOT_PACKAGE_NAME)
{
 ... // Defines the classes and methods in the module
}
```

After that the plug-in is called, and now I want to add more methods to "mymodule" or if not possible, to a new module name, but I can't get it to work!

This is one of ten different ways I've tried, here creating a new module:

```
void OnWizard() // The function that I want to call
{ }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PluginModule)
{
   docstring_options doc_options(true, true, false);
   def("wizard", OnWizard);
}

void PluginDLL::RegisterPythonFunctions()
{

   try {
      // PyImport_AddModule("PluginModule"); // Creates an empty module
      // PyModule_Create(&pluginmodule); // Doesn't seem to work
      // PyImport_AppendInittab("PluginModule", &PyInit_PluginModule); // Needs to be called before Py_Initialize

      // PyImport_ImportModule("PluginModule");
      boost::python::import("PluginModule")
   }
    catch (error_already_set)
    {
       PyErr_Print();
    }
}
```

So how to create a new module after Py_Initialize is executed? And is it possible to either add the "wizard" function to "mymodule" scope or even better "mymodule.PluginModule"?

Any ideas are welcome! Using Boost 1.56 and Python 3.4.